# Running two instances of android device in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets

I'm new to Android app development. I'm trying to write an application which when run on two android devices will be able to communicate through sockets.
I'm little confused on how to test it. I'm using Eclipse in which launches an emulator. How can I get another android device to run my application and how to make socket connections between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the other device using command line. Read this for further guidance:

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run on all available devices.

In your project go to **Properties -> Run/Debug Settings**
select the launch configuration and click **Edit...**
go to the **Target** tab and select **Launch on all compatible devices/AVD's**

Just create a second AVD and bingo